# Result Complement 得到

Tags: grammar, result-complement

The following sentence uses 到 as a result complement but I don't understand why it to has 得 before 到。

他们都想得到比现在更多的东西

Any help identifying the grammar on this one would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

得 = get

The result complement 到 indicate "successfully"

得到 = get/ obtain (successfully)

得 and 到 in '得到' (v + result complement) are tightly bonded. It is treated as an inseparable compound word at the level of words like 獲得 (obtain) or 得以 (able to)

Simply put:

得到 = 獲得 = get/ obtain

Answer (score 2):

Possibly off topic, but:

The meaning of `他们都想得到比现在更多的东西` should be considered in context, and could be very different.

#### #1

尽管他们已经探过整个洞穴，也拿到了不少宝物，但`他们/都/想/得到(de2 dao4)/比/现在/更多的/东西`。
they all want to get more than what they have now.

#### #2

<s>(see edit)</s> 如果他们知道这些情况，`他们/都/想得到(xiang3 de5 dao4)/比/现在/更多的/东西`，也就不会妄自行动了。
they can all figure out more than what we currently have thought. [grammar reference](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Potential_complement)

---

### Edit

the above answer is posted several days ago and I found I made a mistake messing up “的” and “得”, after reviewing my answer.

In the second case, should be “想的到” in stead of “想得到”。 The word starts from “想到” and adding a 的 in the middle indicates the ability of doing something，so “想的到” means being able to figure out.

Comment: Am I correct that the first interpretation takes 到 as the result complement of 得, while the second takes 得到 as the potential compliment of 想?

Comment: @2ndQuantized In the first case, `得到` is a whole word `想 want / 得到 to get`. The second case starts from `想到 figure out` and a `的` in the middle indicates the being able to do something, so `想的到` being able to figure out. It is my bad being careless and messed up 得 and 的, I will edit my answer.

Comment: You were correct the first time, the potential compliment de is 得 not 的, see https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Potential_complement for example.